# Loading a file into innerHTML of a div, but javascript in the file not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, innerhtml

I am loading a .php file into a div I created.
I can successfully load the file into the div and everything works except javascript.
When i test the file in my browser, the javascript works, but not when it's injected into my div.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET["filename"];  
if($filename != ""){        
    $fileData = file_get_contents($filename);
    $fileData = trim($fileData);
    $fileData = str_replace("\n", "", $fileData);
    $fileData = str_replace("\r", "", $fileData);
    echo $fileData;
    die;
}?>

<body>
<script>
function LoadFile(filename, javascriptDiv){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            javascriptDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?filename="+filename,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

var javascriptDiv = document.createElement('div');
javascriptDiv.setAttribute('id', 'javascriptDiv');
javascriptDiv.style.position = 'absolute';  
javascriptDiv.style.top = 50;
javascriptDiv.style.left = 50;
javascriptDiv.style.height = 200;
javascriptDiv.style.width = 300;
javascriptDiv.style.background = '#CCCCCC'; //so we can see that the DIV was created

LoadFile('http://127.0.0.1/Debug/test.php', javascriptDiv);

document.body.appendChild(javascriptDiv); //Display the Window
</script>
</body>
```

**test.php**  <--the file i'm loading into the div

```
Plain text works
<?php echo "<br>php works <br>"; ?>
<a>html works</a><br>

<script>
function Test(){
    alert('javascript works');
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Test Javascript" onclick="Test()"/>
```

**Here's what it looks like on my site.**
[index.php](http://aquawicket.com/Debug/)

**And here is a direct link to the test.php file**
[test.php](http://aquawicket.com/Debug/test.php)

I need to get this working without altering the test.php file.

Comment: If someone is still looking to do this, the easiest way I found was to place an iframe into the div and point the src of the iframe to the file you want to load. Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't evaluate  tags with lazy loading.

Generally speaking, I think the idea of allowing users to run custom javascript is a door open to exploits. I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve and why, but you'd better create a set of functions yourself and publish a simple public API (for example, to get a lightbox, add a 'lightbox' class to your element, or that kind of thing).

Alternatively, you could fetch the content of the  tag and run an eval(). But again, it's dangerous.

[This page](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) explains quite well the different methods you can use to achieve this. Of course, all assume you are running your own code and not some user code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  After thinking about it, you are correct about the danger aspect.  I will make an API to use instead of allowing raw javascript. Thanks

Comment: I'm really trying hard but I can't see why this answer would be downvoted. I'd be grateful if the person who did would explain why.

Comment: My stackoverflow reputation is less than 15 otherwise I'd have voted this answer up.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I don't care about the rating but it's frustrating to not know why. I think this answer is not so bad, therefore I would've liked to know why someone would deem it bad enough to downvote it. I might have learned something (and other people too).

Answer (score 0):

When you pull in content from AJAX, it's up to the browser whether or not to parse any script tags you include [From my experience it's very rare that they do]

Rather than fetching plaintext/html with AJAX, i would recommend fetching JSON encoded info, and then parsing the returned JSON appropriately, e.g.

### new test.php

```
$html=<<<EOT
<input type="button" value="Test Javascript" onclick="Test()"/>
EOT;
$js=<<<EOT
function Test(){
    alert('javascript works');
}
EOT;
echo json_encode(array('html'=>$html,'js'=>$js));
```

### new readystatechange function

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     try{
        respJSON = new Object(xmlhttp.responseText);
        javascriptDiv.innerHTML=respJSON.html;
        eval(respJSON.js);
     }catch (e){
        //!!!
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but is there a way to do it without altering the test.php file?   My users will be creating the files that get loaded so i don't wanna make it too difficult for them to code.

Comment: it's clunky, but you could parse the returned HTML with a RegExp, and eval the extracted js, e.g. `eval(RESPONSE.replace(/<script[^>]+>(.*?)<\/script>/,'$1'))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either define Test function in the parent document or just go like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Test Javascript" onclick="alert('javascript works');"/>
```

In your child document.

Answer (score 0):

Append any HTML tag with display none which is created by using document.createElement or create hidden tag and append it to your file first.

Like this:

```
 var d = document.createElement("hidden");
 div.innerHTML = d + content;
```

It will work fine I tested.